# Converting anki-furigana to HTML-furigana without parser libraries

Tags: html, parsing, haskell

I wrote a converter from anki-style furigana to HTML-style furigana. Eventually I want to do it as a parser, but as a first step I do it without. Furigana is used to write the pronunciation over certain characters in Japanese.

Example:

[image: An example of furigana I found on google images]

- Anki would write it like this:

  ```
  林[はやし]さんは 英語[えいご]は 話[はな]せます。
  ```

  `[]`contains what's written over the char sequence in question and the char seq in question goes from the last `]` to the next `[`. But if the next sequence begins only later (e.g. 英語), `space` is used to indicate that (`\n` works too and there is no nesting of brackets).
- HTML has several ways, and I use this:

  ```
  <ruby><rb>林<rt>はやし</ruby>さんは<ruby><rb>英語<rt>えいご</ruby>は<ruby><rb>話<rt>はな</ruby>せます。
  ```

  A sequence and its pronunciation are enclosed by `<ruby>`, `<rb>` and `<rt>` to indicate what's on top and on the bottom.

The idea is that the string first gets converted into a sequence of tags that may hold text. That sequence is then grouped and after that the tags are converted to HTML.

I'm just wondering if it is OK so far.

```
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    file <- readFile (head args)
    putStrLn (anki_2_html file)

anki_2_html = translate_2_html . group . parse'

data Tag = Kana String | Uptext String
     | Furigana String String
     | Blank | Newline

--convert string to tags                                                                                   
parse' :: String -> [Tag]
parse' string = parse string ""

parse :: String -> String -> [Tag]
parse [] []  = []
parse [] acc = [Kana acc]
parse (l:ls) ""  | l == '['  = parseUpText ls ""
                 | l == ' '  = Blank   : parse ls ""
                 | l == '\n' = Newline : parse ls ""
                 | otherwise = parse ls [l]

parse (l:ls) acc | l == '['        = Kana acc : parseUpText ls ""
                 | l `elem` " \n"  = Kana acc : parse (l:ls) ""
                 | otherwise       = parse ls (acc++[l])

parseUpText :: String -> String -> [Tag]
parseUpText  [] []  = []
parseUpText  [] acc = [Kana (' ':acc)]
parseUpText  (l:ls) []  | l == ']'  = parse  ls ""
                        | otherwise = parseUpText ls [l]

parseUpText  (l:ls) acc | l == ']'   = Uptext acc : parse  ls ""
                        | otherwise = parseUpText ls (acc++[l])

--group patterns of Tags                                                                                   
group :: [Tag] -> [Tag]
group (Blank   : Kana kj : Uptext ka : ms) = Furigana kj ka : group ms
group           (Kana kj : Uptext ka : ms) = Furigana kj ka : group ms
group (m:ms) = m : group ms
group [] = []

translate_2_html ::  [Tag] -> String
translate_2_html = foldl1 (++) . map m2s
          where
            m2s (Furigana below above) = "<ruby><rb>"++below++"<rt>"++above++"</ruby>"
            m2s (Kana k) = k
            m2s (Uptext f) = "<f>" ++ f ++ "</f>"
            m2s Blank  = " "
            m2s Newline= "<br>\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a list like `((... ++ [_]) ++ [_]) ++ [_]` takes quadratic time, [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#break) doesn't.

```
parse :: String -> [Tag]
parse lss = case break (`elem` "[ \n") lss of
  ([],         []) -> []
  ([],     '[':ls) -> parseUpText ls
  ([],     ' ':ls) -> Blank     : parse ls
  ([],    '\n':ls) -> Newline   : parse ls
  (kana,       ls) -> Kana kana : parse ls

parseUpText :: String -> [Tag]
parseUpText lss = case break (== ']') lss of
  ([],         []) -> []
  (kana,       []) -> [Kana (' ':kana)]
  ([],     ']':ls) -> parse ls
  (uptext, ']':ls) -> Uptext uptext : parse ls
```